# Which is the current continuation in the following expression?

Tags: scheme, continuations

In the expression `(call/cc (lambda (k) (k 12)))`, there are three continuations: `(k 12)`, `(lambda (k) (k 12))`, and `(call/cc (lambda (k) (k 12)))`.  Which one is the "current continuation"?

And continuations in some books are viewed as a procedure which is waiting for a value and it will return immediately when it's applied to a value.  Is that right?

Can anyone explain what current continuations are in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like `(k 12)` are not continuations. There is a continuation associated with each subexpression in some larger program. So for example, the continuation of `x` in `(* 3 (+ x 42))` is `(lambda (_) (* 3 (+ _ 42)))`.

In your example, the "current continuation" of `(call/cc (lambda (k) (k 12)))` would be whatever is surrounding that expression. If you just typed it into a scheme prompt, there is nothing surrounding it, so the "current continuation" is simply `(lambda (_) _)`. If you typed something like `(* 3 (+ (call/cc (lambda (k) (k 12))) 42))`, then the continuation is `(lambda (_) (* 3 (+ _ 42)))`.

Note that the lambdas I used to represent the "current continuation" are not the same as what `call/cc` passes in (named `k` in your example). `k` has a special control effect of aborting the rest of the computation after evaluating the current continuation.

Answer (score 1):

The continuation in this case is the "thing" that receives the return value of the `call/cc` invocation. Thus:

```
(display (call/cc (lambda (k) (k 12)))
```

has the same result as

```
(display 12)
```

Continuations in Scheme "look and feel" like procedures, but they do not actually behave like procedures. One thing that can help you understand continuations better is CPS transformations.

---

In CPS transformation, instead of a function returning a value, instead it takes a continuation parameter, and invokes the continuation with the result. So, a CPS-transformed `sqrt` function would be invoked with `(sqrt 64 k)` and rather than returning 8, it just invokes `(k 8)` in tail position.

Because continuations (in a CPS-transformed function) are tail-called, the function doesn't have to worry about the continuation returning, and in fact, in most cases, they are not expected to return.

With this in mind, here's a simple example of a function:

```
(define (hypot x y)
  (sqrt (+ (* x x) (* y y))))
```

and its CPS-transformed version:

```
(define (hypot x y k)
  (* x x (lambda (x2)
           (* y y (lambda (y2)
                    (+ x2 y2 (lambda (sum)
                               (sqrt sum k))))))))
```

(assuming that `*`, `+`, and `sqrt` have all been CPS-transformed also, to accept a continuation argument).

---

So now, the interesting part: a CPS-transformed `call/cc` has the following definition:

```
(define (call/cc fn k)
  (fn k k))
```

With CPS transformation, `call/cc` is easy to understand and easy to implement. Without CPS transformation, `call/cc` is likely to require a highly magical implementation (e.g., via stack copying, etc.).